# Model design for addons in an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I have a Rails app in which the user can subscribe to addons, the list is dynamic and contains currently about 10 addons.

The list specifies which is on/off.

Each addon has a rather unique set of properties.

---

My current solution is that the application has 2 "parent" models and the one new model for each addon:

```
class AddonPrototype
  has_many :addons
end

class Addon
  belongs_to :addon_prototype
  belongs_to :user
end

class AddonAlpha
  belongs_to :addon
end

class AddonBeta
  belongs_to :addon
end

etc..
```

1. The model `AddonPrototype` has one instance of each addon, with the default name as the only property.
2. The model `Addon` with the properties `enabled`, `custom_name`. When the user is visiting the page with addons, a check is done to see whether the user has an `Addon` instance for each existing `AddonPrototype`, or else creating one on the fly.
3. For each addon there is a unique model (e.g. `AddonAlpha`, `AddonBeta` etc), with the set of properties apt for each particular addon.

**This design feels cumbersome, what could be a leaner setup?**

Comment: What exactly are `AddonPrototype`, `AddonAlpha` and `AddonBeta`?

Comment: `AddonPrototype` is the grandparent, the canonical identifier of each unique addon, there would be about ten instances of it. `AddonAlpha` is the grandchild of one of the `AddonPrototype` instances and holds all settings for a particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably missing out on some details, so take this post with a grain of salt.

Currently, the naming of the models seems to be a bit misleading. The `AddonPrototype` is an actual addon, whereas the `Addon` model represents the act of a user having installed an addon.

Here's the structure I would go for:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :installations
  has_many :addons, through: :installations
end

# app/models/addon.rb
class Addon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :installations
  has_many :users, through: :installations
end

# app/models/installation.rb
class Installation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addon
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`AddonPrototype` has been renamed to `Addon`, and the old `Addon` model has been renamed to `Installation` (`Subscription` or something alike would also be a good name).

I would recommend against creating `Installation` records for each addon when a user visits the addons page. Just create these records when a user actually installs an addon. This keeps your code simpler and your database smaller.

Comment: Where would be the best place to store data unique to each Installation if each Addon has a different set of properties (let's say AddonA requires an external API key associated with it and AddonB just requires an email address)?